# Systemverilog elaboration phase info print?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, elaboration

Does anyone know a way to make Systemverilog print something I want one time at the elaboration phase?

I know you can use new $error() system call to print errors at the elaboration phase, but I just want to print info there (not an error) one time. Is it possible to do with $info() call, or is there another way?

Also, preferably the info would print before the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module top;

$info("I could have tried this before posting");

endmodule
```

Comment: I did try that its not working. Is it because info is inside an initial block?

Comment: DUPLICATE POST SORRY

Comment: Maybe your tool/version does not support it. It works for me in ModelSim/Questa. I have no initial block.

Comment: I use Synopsys, usually they are pretty good with keeping up. It could be an order thing... how does it know if an $error goes off in one file and a $info in the other, the order to print those in?

Comment: Actually without an initial block and condition it does print at elaboration time. Only problem is it marks it as a warning.

Comment: That seems like a bug to me. There's no way to control the ordering of elaboration messages. You should provide more details of why you are lokking for this behavior. $error/$fatal will cause the elaboration to stop anyways.

Comment: I tried it on [edaplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/home), Works fine with all versions of Riviera-PRO, but cannot even compile with VCS 2014.12. I'm supersized it is not supported in 2014.12. Elaboration messaging was added in IEEE1800-2009 in § 20.10 _Elaboration system tasks_ (§20.11 in [IEEE1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf))